# What is with the site bashing?

Tags: discussion

We have some new users that just disrespect the site

> I agree the folks on this site are totally clueless about theory and
>   dont understand basic facts, this is not an insult, just a basic fact.

.

> A lot of bad advice here.

.

> So, no, poker is not a game of skill you donkies

.

> Its this Paparazzi troll, I downvoted his answers

.

> I was told I was useless for suggesting to limit scope on a question.

.

> The guy talking about dynamics doesn't understand what a Nash
>   Equilibrium is.

For me once someone has called me a name I just never answer any of their questions.

I just let the mods handle and try and stay away from those users.

Comment: I think you could add in some links for context. Tbh, I suspect negative users are present across most StackEnchange sites.