# Time to appoint a new pro-tempore moderator?

Tags: discussion

Poker is an (almost) unique site in the Stack Exchange network, in the sense that it has only two (pro-tempore) ♦ moderators. [Three is the standard for beta sites](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). As mentioned [here](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/134/3247), one of the initially appointed moderators is no longer active, so only two remain.

That doesn't need to be a problem *per sé*, but the symptoms (IMHO) are. Case in point are spam posts. You can look [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?site=140) to get a feeling for what kind of spam is being posted here; mostly (very) low quality posts with a link to the online poker site of the week. Our bot, [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/) catches a reasonable portion of those, but there are not always six people around to nuke the post (some of our members don't even have an account here). [These](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/79254) [two](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/79253) posts have been on the site for **three days** (with some spam flags, but not enough to destroy them). I'm not sure if this is because it's holiday season, but I expect at least one mod to check up on the site every 24 hours, even on a small site like this one. We've seen more long-living spam on Poker Stack Exchange in the past, so I think this is not just an isolated incident.

Of course, appointing a third ♦ moderator is not guaranteed to solve this problem, but at the very least, it *will* help.

Comment: Aside: not really unique. [scicomp.se], [homebrew.se], [italian.se], [matheducators.se], [productivity.se], [reverseengineering.se], [russian.se], and [rus.se] also have 2 pro tem mods each. (And [pets.se], but they are looking for 3rd right now.)

Comment: @Michelle [you're right](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators), I'll correct that.

Comment: @Paparazzi thanks for stepping up. I'm not sure how this is going to work out; I'm justing stating a problem and a possible solution. It's up to Stack Overflow to decide if they want to open up a nomination thread or not.

Comment: @Glorfindel Then I will delete my comment.

Comment: I would like SE to open a nomination thread, thanks. And perhaps someone could pay attention and give us a hand converter. It's not like the ENTIRE community has been asking for it since day one or anything.

Comment: @Glorfindel Any progress on a new mod or the hand converter?

Comment: @Toby ehm ... I'm just a normal user here, not a Community Manager or something. If you want a new moderator (or an internal discussion) you'll have to contact somebody from the staff, e.g. via the Teachers' Lounge.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks. Calling @Shog9

Answer (score 1):

For the most part it seems like our moderators are keeping up and doing a good job.

2 of my last 5 flags have been aged away.

I have witnessed some hostility lately.  [bashing](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/what-is-with-the-site-bashing)  I wish the mods would be more aggressive.

I am sure SE has a protocol for adding moderators.

I would leave it up to the current moderators if they want another.

Volume on the site overall is a disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

I think another mod would be great. I would like to nominate Paparazzi. He is active and seems to like the site and is a smart guy.

Comment: I am not universally liked here.   Will see when nominations come up but I would be looking for some names other than me.